# Cannot open or start AVI movie file

Tags: rendering, error

It is my first time using blender for animation purposes, but I have a problem because I'm not able to render it, and save it as .avi file.
When I click the Render animation button, this error shows up "Cannot open or start AVI movie file".
Does anyone have a solution for it? Not sure if that's important but I'm using Windows computer. I can also send you the file, to check what is the problem.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please provide blend file. Before uploading, use file->pack resources. thx.

Comment: here it is :) https://univerzamb-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/anastasija_dzudzar_student_um_si/EYfmBRl6A1tEq3rMkpVszTwBl0623RBspzMLVq04j5bknA?e=KEZmYp

Comment: best practice is to render to an image sequence and then do the conversion separately

Comment: Agree with the above, unless it's a fast preview or a video editing, you probably should avoid video output; it's costs more power and isn't fail-proof. Otherwise, it could be an access issue as in the answer below, but also an incorrect set of output settings. Please share with us your file output and encoding settings. I would be careful using AVI in the first place, it was never the most useful format back in its time and there are probably way better options now, like a simple MP4 container with a h264 video track like one of the presets you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your output file path does exist in your output properties. I had the same mistake, changed it to an existing one and it worked.

Hope it helps.